# This code generates error 3061 at .OpenRecordset

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

This code generates error 3061 at .OpenRecordset
See screenshots below.
I am trying to return only records that are Active(Boolean) from a Query called LedgerQuery.
This is so basic. Have I lost my mind?

---

```
Private Sub Example()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM LedgerQuery WHERE Active = " & True

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

rst.Close

End Sub
```

---

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTo7f.jpg)

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjvQ0.jpg)

Comment: Should `True` be within the quotes?

Comment: @urdearboy, the True constant can be within quotes but concatenating should work as well. I also suspect issue is with LedgerQuery. Providing sample data as well as query SQL could be helpful.

Comment: Expecting 2 parameters. `WHERE Active = True AND ...`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an open form from which LedgerQuery pulls two parameter values.

That can be solved like this:

```vb
Private Sub Example()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM LedgerQuery WHERE Active = True"

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDef("", strSQL)
    
    ' Print parameter names.
    Debug.Print qdf.Parameters(0).Name
    Debug.Print qdf.Parameters(1).Name

    ' Set parameter values.
    qdf.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![NameOfYourOpenForm]![NameOfControl1]
    qdf.Parameters(1).Value = [Forms]![NameOfYourOpenForm]![NameOfControl2]
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

    Debug.Print rst.RecordCount
    
    rst.Close

End Sub
```